# Pegar título de um popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Preciso pegar o título ou URL de um *popup*.

Dentro do meu sistema tem um botão, ao clicar abre essa popup com um site externo

Por exemplo:

```
window.open("http://baixaki.com.br/", options);
```

Como faço para pegar o título desse *popup*?

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível pegar dados de uma pop-up de um link externo por causa do [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Apenas a título de curiosidade, se a pop-up fosse de um link interno, você poderia fazer assim:

```
/* ... */
  var win = window.open('link.html');
  win.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log(win.document.title);
  });
/* ... */
```

Comment: mas tem outra maneira de fazer isso ? eu colocar esse site para abrir com cURL etc ? pois o problema é que esse site externo ele abre com uma url e depois de 3 segundos redireciona para outra url, e é essa outra url que eu preciso pegar, eu sei que tem como fazer pq ja vi outros sites que fazem isso, enfim, tem algum jeito de pegar o título ou o url depois do redirecionamento ?

Comment: me mostra um site que tem isso que você tá falando, que se há como, com certeza eu consigo fazer... mas pode ter certeza que é impossível pegar o título de um documento dentro de uma popup quando este documento não é da mesmo domínio de quem abriu a pop-up.

Comment: tem como vc passar seu face ou skype por favor ? pq é muita coisa para falar, e vamos gastar muito tempo trocando mensagens por aqui :/ por favor!